# Excel VBA: Move ActiveCell to Row of Newly Inactive Sheet

Tags: vba, excel

When I move from Sheet1 to Sheet2, what VBA can I use to have the activecell of Sheet2 be the same row as was active on Sheet1 when I switched?

For example: I have Cell B7 active on Sheet1.  When I switch to Sheet2, the activecell moves to the 7th row, (and does not change columns from what it was the last time I was on Sheet2).

Comment: Google will tell you in 3 minutes.

Comment: I have googled extensively.  I cannot find the answer.

Comment: `I have googled extensively. I cannot find the answer` then it must mean it can't be done. sorry :/

Comment: @findwindow but this one is awesome ;)

Comment: @mrbungle I should post that as an answer ~_^

Comment: Just an update: tried some Offset, but I cannot make it work.  Still looking for some suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After really debugging hard on event sequences, I said "Eureka!". The following does what you ask:

```
Private activeRow As Integer, activeCol As Integer
Private sema4 As Integer

Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    If (sema4 > 0) Then Exit Sub
    sema4 = 1
    Sheets(Sh.Name).Activate
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    If (sema4 = 1) Then
        activeRow = Selection.row
        activeCol = Selection.Column
        sema4 = 2
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf (sema4 = 2) Then
        sema4 = 3
        Sheets(Sh.Name).Activate
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf (sema4 = 3) Then
        ActiveSheet.Cells(activeRow, activeCol).Select
        sema4 = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

Again, attach in VB editor to the Workbook.

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you!

PS: Calling a 'flag' sema4 is hilarious.  I've never seen that before.

Comment: `sema4` is short for Semaphore, a sign post. It signals a state in this case to the event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Although the question received a downvote, it is absolutely not trivial. I have only been able to research a partial answer.

Attach the following code to the Workbook (double click on ThisWorkbook in VBA Project Explorer):

```
Private activeRow As Integer, activeCol As Integer

Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    activeRow = Selection.Row
    activeCol = Selection.Column
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    ActiveSheet.Cells(activeRow, activeCol).Select
End Sub
```

The intention is clear: get the selection on the sheet being deactivated and then set the selection on the sheet being acivated.

There only are two problems:

1. Excel has only *one* `Selection` and that is the current selection on the active sheet.
2. The deactivate event occurs *after* the sheet is deactived and the new sheet activated.

As a result, it is not possible to get the last position of the user on the sheet that got deactivated and so we can't set it on the sheet being activated.

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: I've never done it, but could you set up a click event so that every time a new cell is selected the column and row are stored in longs and then when an worksheet change event occurs you can activate the last known .cells(var,var)